# how to get fixed header with css?

Tags: html, css

this is my code and when the page has more content when we scroll the header moves too then i tried making the position of the header `fixed` but then the footer doesn't stick to bottom :/

```
html,body
{
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 8%;
    min-height: 8%;
}
#container
{
    min-height: 85%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
}
footer
{
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    min-height: 6%;
    position: relative;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `position:fixed` to the footter

```
header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 8%;
    min-height: 8%;
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    /*.........^........*/  
    top:0;
}
footer{
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index:1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    min-height: 6%;
    position:fixed;
    /*.........^........*/     
}
```

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/4xDVk/)

Comment: The OP asks about `fixed` **header**, not _footer_.

Comment: @PranavRam it is not the footer i want to be fixed its the header i want to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
footer
    {
       position: fixed; 
       z-index: 300; 
       bottom: 0px; 
       left: 0px;
       background-color: #000000;
       width: 100%;
       height: 6%;
       min-height: 6%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ws2H/3/)

```
header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 8%;
    min-height: 8%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
footer
{
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    min-height: 6%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Here i've mentioned `height: 1000px;` for your understanding... you can change it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/6w2p8/)**

```
header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 8%;
    min-height: 8%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
footer
{
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    min-height: 6%;
    position: absolute;

}
```